# How can I prove that $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega + \omega^{-1}) :\mathbb{Q}]=\frac{\varphi (n)}{2}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, totient-function

> If $n>2$, $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$ an $n$-th primitive root of unity then $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega + \omega^{-1}) :\mathbb{Q}]=\frac{\varphi (n)}{2}$. ($\varphi (n)$ is the Euler totient function.)

How can I prove it?

Answer (score 3):

We have 
$$
\phi(n)=[\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}(\omega +\omega^{-1})][\mathbb{Q}(\omega +\omega^{-1}):\mathbb{Q}],
$$
where $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega):\mathbb{Q}(\omega +\omega^{-1})]=2$, since $t^2-(\omega+\omega^{-1})t+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\omega+\omega^{-1})$. It follows that 
$$[\mathbb{Q}(\omega +\omega^{-1}):\mathbb{Q}]=\frac{\phi(n)}{2}.$$

Comment: Shouldn't the constant term be a $1$ ? How do you know that this polynomial is irreducible / that $\Bbb Q(\omega) \neq \Bbb Q(\omega + \omega^{-1})$ ?

Comment: @mercio: Yes, thank you, a typo. Of course, $\mathbb{Q}(\omega+\omega^{-1})$ is a real field, but $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ not for $n>2$. Hence they cannot be equal.